# laravel framework authenticate system users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Currently I have assigned to the software project.We are developing the education web portal.The main parts of the system are teacher,student and admin.Teachers and student can register to the web portal by using there details.Admin is responsible to accept the request of  registration of student and teachers.I am going to do this task by using Laravel Framework.And also i going to use vue.js,xammp,mysql,html5,css technologies.Is there any other useful technologies to do this task?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Yes, Laravel can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I'll give you a simple solution and then you will adapt it in your project.

Start with adding a `accepted` flag into the users table, then every time that a user registers into your application you set this flag to false, now you can build your page to list every user that hasn't been already accepted with some sort of action that allows the admin to make the update on the specific user table and set that flag to true.